# How do I find out what triggers induced GCs in ASP.NET MVC application hosted on IIS?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, garbage-collection

We observe that most of Gen2 (full) garbage collections in our app are induced, but struggle to find what actually triggers them. In particular, setting a breakpoint on GC.Collect doesn't help.

Moreover, we know that the app is far from consuming most of available memory before triggering Gen2 GCs -- typically it uses just about 8 GB out of ~ 14 or 30 GB available.

So there are actually two questions:

- What are some good ways to find out what code triggers induced GCs?
- Is there any way to somehow completely suppress induced GCs?

We use IIS 8 and .NET Framework 4.6.2.

Comment: Any line of code that causes memory to be allocated *may* cause the system to decide that its time to perform a collection.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104741/tracking-down-the-source-of-net-4-0-induced-gc

Comment: The question is not about general GCs, but about induced GCs. + As I said, I feel there is no any reason to do a full GC at the point they actually happen in our case.

Comment: I'm no expert, but perhaps this can shed some light: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx